# Can I cancel an unconfirmed transaction?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

I made a transaction by mistake, fortunately it is still unconfirmed.

Can I cancel it?

Comment: You could perhaps doublespend it to yourself. What wallet are you using?

Comment: Multibit HD. There is no double spending option there. I've tried reinstalling the wallet in a new computer, reseting, repairing, everything you can imagine. That stupid wallet always fetches that unconfirmed transaction from the network. Don't know how to double spend it....

Comment: There is no way to cancel an unconfirmed transaction, and it has already been asked here. Flagging to close.